# Espaço indevido no layout! como resolver?

Tags: android, android-layout

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Apareceu um espaço indevido no projeto do android... Como posso resolver?

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.wbsotware.wesley.forecast.MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="500dp"
    android:src="@drawable/bgverde"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Esse espaço não fará parte da imagem?

Comment: Não... quero que ela fica encostada no top. Em algumas resoluções de tela ela fica no topo, em outras não.

Comment: Coloque `android:scaleType="fitXY"` na sua imageView e a mágica acontecerá. Se funcionar, você pode adicionar uma resposta na sua pergunta mostrando como resolveu ;)

Comment: Acredito que esse problema esteja relacionado ao fato do aplicativo estar com a toolbar superior ativa no styles.xml. Se não funcionar a solução do @itscorey, poste seu styles.xml, por favor.